# How to use ngrok with rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ngrok

I am using rails 5.2 and I want to use ngrok to recieve webhooks.
When i try to add this line

```
Rails.application.config.hosts << "product.com"
```

in development.rb and I get that config.hosts is not available until rails 6. Can anyone help what is equivalent to it on rails 5.2?

Comment: Your host would be http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000 for development.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your development server running locally to receive webhook calls, you can run ngrok like this:

```
ngrok http YOUR_RAILS_PORT_NUMBER
```

Then,  ngrok will give you a url that you can use for the webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

Run ngrok at running rails port:

```bash
ngrok http 3000
```

You will get ngrok link to receive webhooks, paste it without `https://` in `developement.rb`:

```bash
config.hosts << "5a86-58-27-193-244.ngrok-free.app"
```

Restart your rails server and you will be good to go.